# permission denied (public key) when pulling through a different pc

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a private repository in bitbucket. I want to work from two pcs. First one will be my home pc and another will be my work pc.

1. For work pc, i want it to prompt for password
2. For home pc, I don't want it to prompt for password

In my home pc, i haved added the SSH keys and i am able to push,pull etc. without any issues.

Now When i try to do a clone from my work pc, it just says permission denied (public key) I

I actually expected that it will ask me for the password. What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[EDITED: adding another solution after understanding the issue more]

There are a couple possible solutions:

## SSH Private Keys with passphrase

you want a signed private key. I would probably add a separate key to you bitbucket account and use the signed key from your work computer. When you create a key, it should ask for a pass phrase and it is my understanding that the passphrase protects the private key from being valid without it. There are tons of guides out there, but this one seems reasonable.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSH_Keys#Choosing_the_key_location_and_passphrase

## use a different protocol for fetching

git, but default uses the git protocol. if you open your git configuration you will notice the endpoint begins with `git://`. Git uses a custom protocol for transfering git objects, but uses SSH to authenticate the user, thus the need for the public/private keys and SSH in order to use git. Because SSH is not installed by default on some operating systems, namely Windows, git hosting providers have added HTTPS as another protocol for authentication. Typically you would change your endpoint to use `https:` in your git config and you will then communicate over that protocol and use standard username/password credentials to authenticate.

for bitbucket: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Use+the+SSH+protocol+with+Bitbucket

for github: https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use

## how I would do it

While done by most people, it is considered bad practice to have an RSA key without a passphrase. This leaves you private key in a plain state on your hard drive, so you have to assume that anyone with access to your computer can assume your identity. Adding a passphrase encrypts the key on the hard drive. With a strong passphrase, the private key is quite secure (though I am no security expert) so it would be difficult, even with access to the key, to assume an identity without the passphrase. That being said, keyloggers are an obvious choice to get around that. Github now offers two factor auth: https://help.github.com/articles/about-two-factor-authentication which might be the most secure way at the moment. In my mind however, the passphrase secured RSA key is, for me, closest to the junction of convenience and security.

Comment: what if i don't want to add any key in my work computer. I just want to work with it as I would without using SSH keys authentication...Just let it ask me password everytime i push/pull

Comment: i should have probably mentioned, the git configuration is remote specific so you can use one protocol from home, and another on a separate remote at work.

Comment: I was exactly looking for something like the second approach i.e using different protocols! Thanks :)